# Enumerable.Concat more than two parameters c#

Tags: c#, string, concatenation, enumerable

I have 4 collections containing strings, like this:

first: xxxxxxxx
second: xx
third: xxxxxxxx
fourth: xx

I want to concat these 4 collections to get: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

I wanted to use the Enumerable.Concat but I have one problem with this, It only take two parameters. As a consequence I can concat only the first with the second (for example) but not all of'em together.

Is c# offers a way to concat more than 2 collections together?

Am I having to create two collections which concat first + second and third + fourth and then concat the two collections together?

***EDIT***

I made a mistake, It's 4 collections I want to concat. These collections contains strings like shown before, but these are Collections

Comment: Do you want one long collection of strings, or one long string?

Comment: I just want to concat the 4 collections as 1, so a long collection of strings should be the good solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can chain the `Enumerable.Concat` calls like this.

```
List<string> list1 = new List<string>();
List<string> list2 = new List<string>();
List<string> list3 = new List<string>();
List<string> list4 = new List<string>();

//Populate the lists

var mergedList = list1.Concat(list2)
    .Concat(list3)
    .Concat(list4)
    .ToList();
```

Another option is to create an array and call `SelectMany`

```
var mergedList = new[]
{
    list1, list2, list3, list4
}
.SelectMany(x => x)
.ToList();
```

Note: `Enumerable.Concat` will allow duplicate elements, if you want to eliminate duplicates you can use `Enumerable.Union` method, rest all same.

Comment: Thanks, sound precisely what I was look for. I think I don't have to use Union, this Concat is only to make a comparison between the concat values and another value, But I'll remember it.

Comment: @Flo Added alternative way of doing the same, If not useful now it is good to be aware of something exist.

Comment: I have made this, applying your first solution:  `foreach (var item in viewModel.ActiviteCollection.Where(c => c.PMRQTOTMActivite ==  Enumerable.Concat(data.Pmid, data.Ligne).Concat(data.Otm).Concat(data.Totm)))`

And sounds working great

Comment: In addition `SelectMany(x => x)`, you can also use `Aggregate(Enumerable.Concat)`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `string.Concat` method, `Enumerable.Concat` is meant for collections.

You could also use `+` operator.

Please note, that strings are immutable objects. It means that when you add 2 string, a new string object is being created. Therefore, for memory optimization purposes, you should use `StringBuilder` class for dynamic strings and concatenation of more than 5 strings.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, you made me realise I made a mistake, these are collections I aim to concat. These are collections of string, but it's still collection. That's why I used Enumerable.Concat

Answer (score 0):

If it's only four strings, what's wrong with:

```
first+ second+ third+ forth;
```

???

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to take any special action yourself if you are concatenating 4 strings or less.

Firstly, note that [there are overloads of `String.Concat()` taking between one and four `string` parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.concat%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Secondly, note that the compiler will translate concatenations involving four or less strings into calls to the appropriate `String.Concat()` overload.

For example, consider this code:

```
string a = "a";
string b = "b";
string c = "c";
string d = "d";
string e = a + b + c + d;
```

The concatenation is turned into this IL:

```
.method private hidebysig static void Main(string[] args) cil managed
{
    .entrypoint
    .maxstack 4
    .locals init (
        [0] string a,
        [1] string b,
        [2] string c,
        [3] string d,
        [4] string e)
    L_0000: ldstr "a"
    L_0005: stloc.0 
    L_0006: ldstr "b"
    L_000b: stloc.1 
    L_000c: ldstr "c"
    L_0011: stloc.2 
    L_0012: ldstr "d"
    L_0017: stloc.3 
    L_0018: ldloc.0 
    L_0019: ldloc.1 
    L_001a: ldloc.2 
    L_001b: ldloc.3 
    L_001c: call string [mscorlib]System.String::Concat(string, string, string, string)
    L_0021: stloc.s e
    L_0023: ldloc.s e
    L_0025: call void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
    L_002a: ret 
}
```

Note that the actual concatenation is done by a call to `System.String::Concat(string, string, string, string)`.

If you are concatenating more strings, you might want to consider using `StringBuilder` instead, but you will probably only see a speed improvement for more than 8 or so strings.

---

[EDIT] OK the OP completely changed the question from concatenating strings to concatenating collections of strings... so this answer is now pointless. :(

Comment: Indeed, but thank you for the anwser, It'll be very usefull soon on my project.